# Sorting an array nested in an object which is nested in another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, nested

I have an object called 'team' with a set of nested objects for each team name. In that team name I have the players, and I am looking to sort each array dynamically instead of doing it for each team.xxxx.player.sort();

```
var team = {
    fnatic: {
        team: "Fnatic",
        player: ["Olofmeister", "JW", "Pronax", "Krimz", "Flusha"]
    },
    titan: {
        team: "Titan",
        player: ["Ex6Tenz", "shox", "RpK", "SmithZz", "Maniac"]
    },
    nip: {
        team: "Ninjas in Pyjamas",
        player: ["GeT_RiGhT", "f0rest", "allu", "friberg", "XizT"]
    },
    nv: {
        team: "EnVy Us",
        player: ["kennyS", "apeX", "NBK-", "Happy", "kioShiMa"]
    },

    vp: {
        team: "Virtus Pro",
        player: ["PashaBiceps", "Taz", "byali", "Snax", "Xx"]
    }
};
```

I am trying to sort the player array alphabetically (team.XXXX.player). I've found that I can do this by typing

```
team.fnatic.player.sort();
```

for each individual team, but I want to iterate over the object, because I will have a large quantity of teams with players to sort.

Thanks to [Arne Martin Aurlien on his blog and his object sort function](http://am.aurlien.net/post/1221493460/sorting-javascript-objects) this is as close as I've come with what I have searched and read on here:

```
for (var obj in team) {
    if (team.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
        console.log(obj, team[obj].player);  //line 107
        [obj].player = sortObj(team[obj].player);
        console.log(obj, team[obj].player);  //line 109
    }
}
```

This unfortunately still only prints out the unsorted array:

```
fnatic ["Olofmeister", "JW", "Pronax", "Krimz", "Flusha"] script.js:107
fnatic ["Olofmeister", "JW", "Pronax", "Krimz", "Flusha"] script.js:109
titan ["Ex6Tenz", "shox", "RpK", "SmithZz", "Maniac"] script.js:107
titan ["Ex6Tenz", "shox", "RpK", "SmithZz", "Maniac"] script.js:109
...etc for each team
```

I feel that I am missing something simple here. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I believe the `sort` function does not change the original values.  If that's your desired behaviour, you will need to assign the output of `.sort()` back into the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the team keys:

```
Object.keys(team).forEach(function(key) {
    team[key].player.sort();
});
```

Sort is in place ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)):

> The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns
>   the array. The sort is not necessarily stable. The default sort order
>   is according to string Unicode code points.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood what Arne Martin Aurlien was doing, when he wrote that function.

He wanted a way to sort the object properties, and not an array inside an object. What he tried to do fails by design, since the ECMAScript specification says that the object properties aren't indexed.

As you can see in his post, he says:

> Be careful using this with Chrome. If your object has both numbers and strings as keys, Chrome will sort the object with the number-keys first, even when sorting by value.

And that's not an error, since the specification clearly says that what he tried to do, it can't be done.

---

Backing to your question, what you want to do is: Sort the array inside the object.

So, you were already almost there. Your code should be something like that:

```
for (var obj in team) {
    if (team.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {
        console.log(obj, team[obj].player);
        team[obj].player.sort(); // you only need to call the sort method here
        console.log(obj, team[obj].player);
    }
}
```

If I'm right, what you haven't get when trying to understand what was going on, is that you can get a property of an object in Javascript both by calling it directly (e.g `team.fnatic.player`), and by calling it by string (e.g `team['fnatic'].player`), and that's why you can loop through the object and get all the child objects, to get the `players` property (which is an Array), and then sort that array.